# Mysql Database with Flask (Page keeps Refreshing)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am new to python and flask. I have been working with MySQL.python connector to connect to the database with flask. The issues that i am having, is trying to take the input data from the webpage and have it appear in MySQL. From everything I have learned so far is using the (details = request.form) to pull data from the HTML and insert it into a variable and running code like that. When I press submit on the webpage, it refreshes it and no data has been added to the database.

If you all can help, it will be much appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import mysql.connector
app = Flask(__name__)


conn= mysql.connector.connect (
host = 'localhost' ,
user = 'root',
password = '',

database = 'db_randolph',)

if (conn):                                               # this connects to the database and has a if statment that says if it workds or not. 
    print ("Connected Successfully")
else:
    print ("Connection Not Established")


mycursor = conn.cursor()



mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/ADD', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_Artist ():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = request.form
        artist_name = details['artist_name']
        ablum_name = details['ablum_name']
        song_name = details[ 'song_name']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        artist = "INSERT INTO p_artist(artist_name) VALUES (%s)"  # this is the add screen for the site and it will flash a message when complete. When things are submitted the page refresh with submitting things to the database. 
        song = "INSERT INTO p_track_name(track_name) VALUES (%s)"
        ablum = "INSERT INTO p_ablum(ablum_name) VALUES (%s)"
        mycursor.commit(artist, artist_name)
        mycursor.commit(song, song_name)
        mycursor.commit(ablum, ablum_name)
        mycursor.close()
        Flash("The infomation has suscessfully been inserted into database")
        return redirect( "home.html")

    return render_template('add.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> music Page </title>
<style> 
Body {
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: pink;
}
button { 
       background-color: #4CAF50; 
       width: 100%;
        color: orange; 
        padding: 15px; 
        margin: 10px 0px; 
        border: none; 
        cursor: pointer; 
         } 
 form { 
        border: 3px solid #f1f1f1; 
    } 
 input[type=text], input[type=password] { 
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 8px 0;
        padding: 12px 20px; 
        display: inline-block; 
        border: 2px solid green; 
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
 button:hover { 
        opacity: 0.7; 
    } 
  .cancelbtn { 
        width: auto; 
        padding: 10px 18px;
        margin: 10px 5px;
    } 
      
   
 .container { 
        padding: 25px; 
        background-color: lightblue;
    } 
</style> 
<title> Artist Table Database</title>
</head>  
<body>  


    <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/Delete_Ablum">Delete Ablum</a></p>
  
    <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/Delete_Artist">Delete Artist</a></p>
  
    <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/Delete_Songs">Delete Artist</a></p>

    <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/Home">Home</a></p>

    <center> <h1> Add Artist, Name, Song and Ablum Infomation </h1> </center> 
    <form>
        <div class="container"> 
            <label>Artist Name: </label> 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Artist Name" name="artist_name" >
            <label>Artist Ablum : </label> 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Ablum Name" name="ablum_name">
            <label> Song </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Song" name="song_name" >
            <button type="submit">Enter Artist Infomation</button> 
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me 
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn"> Cancel</button> 
            Forgot <a href="#"> password? </a> 
        </div> 
    </form>  
 <table> 

 </table>   
    
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: try `request.get_data()`, it will return `POST` body bytes data

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified that the form method is 'POST', from what I can tell, form invokes the 'GET' method (You can check this by printing request.method), ergo, the 'if request.method == 'POST':' isn't met, go to your  tag and add this:

```
<form action = "/add" method = "POST">
```

Then try it again.

Also, you might want to add an id to your button, like this

```
<button type="submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Just in-case you would like to use JavaScript for something.